# How does NuGet contentFiles work?

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to create a nuget package with content which work with different kinds of projects.

TestSource.nuspec look like this:

    `<contentFiles>
      <files include="cs\any\TestSource.cs" buildAction="Compile" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
  <files> 
    <file src="TestFolder\TestSource.cs" target="content/TestFolder" />
  </files>`

(the file is available both as `contentFiles\cs\any\TestSource.cs` and `TestFolder\TestSource.cs`)

The created package works fine in a "normal" project but nothing happens in a packagereference project.

I assume I'm missing something simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this out myself.

You need to add the file twice in the files section

```
  <contentFiles>
    <files include="cs\any\TestSource.cs" buildAction="Compile" />
  </contentFiles>
</metadata>
<files> 
  <file src="TestFolder\TestSource.cs" target="content/TestFolder" />
  <file src="TestFolder\TestSource.cs" target="contentFiles/cs/any" />
</files>
```

The package will then work for both normal and packagereference projects.

Comment: <files> will tell the package where to get the files from while it is being **packed**. <contentFiles> will tell the package what to **extract** when the project containing this package is built. Compare the .nuspec file you're creating your package from with the one inside of the resulting package. You'll notice that the <files> element is gone while <contentFiles> is still present (and sometimes a bit altered by the packing process). The reasoning behind this is, that the origin of the files is irrelevant, once the package has been packed.