# .NET Core adding/building .cs files to target project

Tags: c#, configuration, .net-core, nuget

I am trying to setup a NuGet package for some c bindings.
I want some .cs files to be added/built into the target project.

I got this to work for .NET Framework using the content target but that is not supported in .NET Core.

Similar issue - [How does NuGet contentFiles work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542386/how-does-nuget-contentfiles-work)

I tried that solution but it fails to build in the target project. The two folders content and contentFiles in the package folder are there so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

The nuspec file is in the same folder as the files I want to be copied. I want to specify it so they are put inside a folder in the target project.

Comment: What's the folder and file structure of your nupkg? The project that references the project, is it using packages.config or PackageReference? If it's PackageReference, does the obj\project.assets.json file contain any sections on your nupkg, and if so, which assets does it list?

Comment: NuGet have a contentFiles sample as well, which might help: https://github.com/NuGet/Samples/tree/master/ContentFilesExample

Comment: The nuspec file is in with the project directly. I found the project.assets.json file for the target, it only mentions it once with the target and vesion number.

Comment: The example is similar but doesn't use the files tag aswell. I looked at the docs but I am confused as to how to fix it. Is there a way I can debug what it is doing?